# Javascript: Round by 100

Tags: javascript, math, numbers, rounding

I'm trying to round a number the 100.

Example:

```
1340 should become 1400
1301 should become 1400
```

and

```
298 should become 300
200 should stay   200
```

I know about `Math.round` but it doesn't round to the 100.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Divide by 100, round, then multiply that result by 100 :-)

Comment: Everything integers, or also non-integral values?

Comment: don't tag it with jquery

Comment: I wonder if any of the people below that marked this as a duplicate actually read the question.  I think not.

Comment: @Alex - if you want to always round **up**, use Archer's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
function roundUp(value) {
    return (~~((value + 99) / 100) * 100);
}
```

That will round up to the next hundred - 101 will return 200.

jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/r8ryd/

Open your console to see the results.

Answer (score 23):

### Original Answer

Use the `Math.ceil` function, such as:

```
var result = 100 * Math.ceil(value / 100);
```

---

### Generalised Version

This function can be generalised as follows:

```
Number.prototype.roundToNearest = function (multiple, roundingFunction) {
    // Use normal rounding by default
    roundingFunction = roundingFunction || Math.round;

    return roundingFunction(this / multiple) * multiple;
}
```

Then you can use this function as follows:

```
var value1 = 8.5;
var value2 = 0.1;

console.log(value1.roundToNearest(5));              // Returns 10
console.log(value1.roundToNearest(5, Math.floor));  // Returns 5
console.log(value2.roundToNearest(2, Math.ceil));   // Returns 2
```

Or with a custom rounding function (such as [banker's rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)):

```
var value1 = 2.5;
var value2 = 7.5;

var bankersRounding = function (value) {
    var intVal   = Math.floor(value);
    var floatVal = value % 1;

    if (floatVal !== 0.5) {
        return Math.round(value);
    } else {
        if (intVal % 2 == 0) {
            return intVal;
        } else {
            return intVal + 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(value1.roundToNearest(5, bankersRounding)); // Returns 0
console.log(value2.roundToNearest(5, bankersRounding)); // Returns 10
```

An example of the code running is [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/pwn8mshp/).